# Typeahead + Jquery + TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function + .mixin(Typeahead.prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

In my html page, I am trying to add Typeahead for autocomplete, but I am not able to resolve one issue related to **TypeError** and **ReferenceError**.

I tried one sample on CodePen and working fine. [Click Here](http://codepen.io/rpatil/pen/rmDsB?editors=101)

But in actual page, I am getting those error.

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
.mixin(Typeahead.prototype, {

typeahe...?body=1 (line 87, col 2)
TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function
```

**HTML Code**

```
var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5'];
$('#search').typeahead({source: subjects})
```

**Arrangement of JS file**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'angular.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap.3.2.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'typeahead.js' %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.backstretch.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.scrollTo.min.js' %>
```

Please suggest some thing to resolve this. I saw few solution on google and stackoverflow but nothing is working.
[image]

**Please have a look at updated answer area**

Comment: Straight from the browser console: _"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://raw.githubusercontent.com/twitter/typeahead.js/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js"_

Comment: Please have a look at image. Just updated

Comment: Thanks a lot @War10ck for one suggestion and I just worked on that. I tried few thing and By modifying one line and problem get resolved. I am not sure how sure I am but I am getting the drop-down

Answer (score 2):

Very Very Silly Mistake - May be I am wrong ...

I found the issue with Bootstrap Javascript JS file that I added.

In sample code, I have added bootstrap 2.3.2 version and working fine.

```
twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

But in my html page, I have added bootstrap 3.2 js version and create the conflict as I assume.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap.3.2.js' %>
```

**Right now I just replaced 3.2 version with 2.3.2 version and working fine.**